# Why does $223$ require $37$ terms to be expressed as a sum of positive fifth powers?

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

I saw [this post](https://twitter.com/AlgebraFact/status/1403005346902388736) about the number earlier today with this formula.

$a_1^5 + a_2^5 + \cdots + a_k^5$, if $k < 37$

Why is it that $223$ is the only number to have to be $37$ or up to be represented by powers of five?

Comment: Can you link to the post?

Comment: Here you go Toby - https://twitter.com/AlgebraFact/status/1403005346902388736

Comment: In its current form, the statement is false. $223 = 4^5 + 4\times(-3)^5 + 5\times(2^5) + 11\times 1^5$ is a sum of $21$ fifth powers. One probably need to impose some extra conditions of $a_k$ (distinct?) for the statement to work.

Comment: The $a_i$ need to be natural numbers. They need not be distinct.

Comment: $223 = (6 \times 2^5) + (31 \times 1^5)$, where no negative terms are allowed.  The issue is, for all positive integers $k$ such that $2^5 \leq k < 3^5$, if $k$ is expressed in base $(32)$ as $(32 \times a) + b$, what is the maximum value that the sum $(a + b)$ will take on, as $k$ ranges from $32$ through $242$?

Comment: My attempt to construct another such number, namely $465 = 3^5 + (7 \times 2^5) + 30$ fails, since $465$ can also be expressed as $(14 \times 2^5) + 17.$

Answer (score 3):

[Waring's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) states that, given $k$, every number can be represented as the sum of at most $s$ $k$-th powers, i.e. that the number of $k$-th powers you need does not keep growing for larger numbers. Apparently this was proven by David Hilbert.

Given that there is a bound, there must be at least one number that is is the worst case. For $5$th powers the bound happens to be $37$, and there happens to be only one number that attains that bound which is $223=6\cdot2^5+31\cdot1^5$.

$3^5=243=7\cdot2^5+19\cdot1^5$, so you won't need more than $37$ fifth powers for any other number below that. For larger numbers it gets trickier, because the "greedy" algorithm where you use as many large fifth powers as possible does not always work.

For example, the greedy algorithm would give $3000 = 2\cdot4^5 + 3\cdot3^5 +6\cdot2^5 + 31\cdot1^5$, using $42$ fifth powers, but by breaking up one of the $4^5$ terms you get $3000 = 1\cdot4^5 + 8\cdot3^5 +1\cdot2^5$ which uses only $10$ fifth powers.

For larger numbers there is much more flexibility in the representations allowing you to keep the number of powers below $37$. Actually proving that there is always enough flexibility to do this is difficult.